# Subsets with random sampling with replacement in R

Tags: r, statistics, random, training-data

I have a vector of 300 numbers (from 1 to 300). I want to create two subsets, i.e., model/training (200 numbers) and testing set (100 numbers) with replacement. I tried to use `sample` and `subset` but didn't got the results I want.

```
MWE:
x=(1,2,3,.......300)
x1 = (1,1,2,3,5,5,...........,300) (Consider it training set of 200 samples)
x2 = (1,3,9,101,130,130,..........299)
```

Any suggestion please !!!!!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using R

Comment: How did you try with `sample` and how were the results not what you wanted?

Comment: Following is the example
> x = seq(from=1, to=300, by=1)
> x
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 ....... 300
 a= sample(x, size=100, replace=TRUE, prob=NULL)
a= sample(x, size=200, replace=TRUE, prob=NULL)

Comment: So what is it that you do not like about the `sample` output? That it is not sorted? Does your question boil down to "how does one sort a vector"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a set of random indices for the training set and then select all but those indices for the test set, like this:

```
data <- c(1,3,8,7,19,5,4,10,11,20)
i <- sample(1:length(data), 5)
training <- data[i]
test <- data[-i]
```

This will get five points for the training set and all the remaining points will go in the test set.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. However, if I want to have a test set which contains the combination of indices not included in the training set and indices included in the training set (random sampling with replacement again). Can I do that ?

Comment: Sure, just replace the final line with: test <- sample(data, desiredSampleSize, replace=TRUE), where desiredSampleSize is how large you'd like your test data set to be.